# NameError at /gmailAuthenticate/ NameError: name 'xsrfutil' is not defined

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want the visitor of this website to get authenticated via Gmail API.

Getting the following error on the line 24 in views.py (at the line FLOW.params['state']):

```
NameError at /gmailAuthenticate/
name 'xsrfutil' is not defined
```

Views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import CredentialsModel
import httplib2
import requests
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from gfglogin import settings
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from oauth2client.contrib.django_util.storage import DjangoORMStorage
from oauth2client.contrib.django_util.models import CredentialsField
# Create your views here.

FLOW = flow_from_clientsecrets(
    settings.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRETS_JSON,
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
    redirect_uri='http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth2callback',
    prompt='consent')

def gmail_authenticate(request):
    storage = DjangoORMStorage(CredentialsModel, 'id', request.user, 'credential')
    credential = storage.get()

    if credential is None or credential.invalid:

        FLOW.params['state'] = xsrfutil.generate_token(settings.SECRET_KEY,
                                                            request.user)
        authorize_url = FLOW.step1_get_authorize_url()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(authorize_url)
    else:
        http = httplib2.Http()
        http = credential.authorize(http)
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', http = http)
        print('access_token = ', credential.access_token)
        status = True

        return render(request, 'index.html', {'status': status})
```

Urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^gmailAuthenticate/', views.gmail_authenticate, name ='gmail_authenticate'),
    url(r'^oauth2callback/', views.auth_return),
    url(r'^$', views.home, name ='home'),
]
```

Unable to understand what could be the cause.

Answer (score 1):

You are not importing `xsrfutil`. You need to import that by adding 
`from oauth2client.contrib import xsrfutil`

Here is the link for the docs [oauth2client.contrib.xsrfutil module](https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.contrib.xsrfutil.html)
.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like xsrfutil is part of [outh2client.contrib](https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.contrib.xsrfutil.html). You aren't importing it. Add it in:

```
from oauth2client.contrib import xsrfutil
```